# Which Indo-Aryan languages exhibit full assimiliation of voiced stops after nasal segments?

Tags: phonology, indo-aryan, nasals, nasalization

In which Indo-Aryan languages, if any, is full assimilation of voiced stops after nasal segments a characteristic feature? Particularly among Punjabi, Sindhi, Saraiki, Kashmiri, Dogri, Kangri, Garhwali, Kumaoni.

Comment: In Iranian there are things like Middle Persian bandag > bannag “slave”. But I am not sure about Indo-Aryan.